# Check the uniform convergence of the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=\dfrac{n^2x}{1+n^3x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Check the uniform convergence of the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=\dfrac{n^2x}{1+n^3x^2}$ over the interval $[0,1]$

The sequence is pointwise convergent to zero function. Also $f'_n(x)=0$ at $x=\pm \frac{1}{n^{2.5}}$. The problem is that how to conclude that these are the point of maxima or minima. Since to calculate second derivative is a tidious job.